# An in place Partition which returns the Pivot position

Tags: algorithm, pivot, quicksort, divide-and-conquer, data-partitioning

Since a normal partition returns an index j such that each element with index i <= j is less than the choisen pivot, and each element with index m > j is bigger than the pivot, there are no guarantees that j is the pivot. Would it be possible to create another in place partition algorithm which returns exactly the new pivot position?
Initially, I tought of moving the choisen pivot in the last position, but it does not lead to an optimal solution though.

Comment: 'there are no guarantees that j is the pivot' Counterexample please? I mean, (if I understand your question correctly) can you make a list of numbers and pivot, so that partitioning does not give the correct position for the pivot?

Comment: Let's define A = {5,3,2,6,4,1,3,7}, and let be the pivot 5, executing the partition it d output this {3,3,2,1,4,6,5,7} and j d be the index of 4.

Comment: Your example looks wrong. If the the pivot is 5, only numbers smaller than 5 should be left of it and also only numbers bigger than 5 should be to the right of it (and 5 should be in the middle).

Comment: Actually my partition looks like this one: 
`Partition (A, p, r)
   x = A[p]
   i = p-1
   j = r+1
   while true do
      repeat j=j-1 until A[j]≤ x
      repeat i=i+1 until A[i]≥ x
      if i < j then swap A[i] ↔ A[j]
      else return j`

and executing it should produce the output i wrote above.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to keep the pivot out of the swapping, except at the very beginning when you store it away at one of the boundaries and at the end when you swap it into its correct place.

```
int partition(int *A, int low, int high) {

    if (high <= low) return low; // in that case, partition shouldn't be called, but cater for it

    int pivot_position = low;  // or high, or low + (high-low)/2, or whatever
    int pivot = A[pivot_position];

    A[pivot_position] = A[high];
    A[high] = pivot;    // these two lines are unnecessary if pivot_position == high
    int i = low, j = high-1;

    while(i < j) {

        while(i < j && A[i] <= pivot)
            ++i;   // i == j or A[i] > pivot, and A[k] <=pivot for low <= k < i

        while(i < j && A[j] > pivot) 
            --j;   // i == j or A[j] <= pivot, and A[m] > pivot for j < m < high

        if (i < j) {
            int temp = A[j];
            A[j] = A[i];
            A[i] = temp;
        }
    }
    if (A[i] <= pivot) 
        ++i;

    // now A[k] <= pivot for low <= k < i and A[m] > pivot for i <= m < high
    A[high] = A[i];
    A[i] = pivot;
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks, it works, so my initial idea was ok, but i do miss the part of executing the partition only on Array[1..n-1] and the swapping of the pivot with the 1st element bigger than it. Thanks again :)